# Can error from Javascript cause Selenium tests fail?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I am writing automation test for a Rail app using Selenium, Capybara and Cucumber running on Jenkins. Recently, lots of my tests failed due to error:

```
unknown error: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Linux 4.0.5 x86_64) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)
./features/step_definitions/advanced_search.rb:81:in `/^user can see search buttons and links$/'
```

and in Chrome inspect, I can see a javascript error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined
```

So, I want to know if this javascript error can make my tests failed? This error only appears after clicking on an element. Have anyone experienced this error? How to solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a JS error can cause tests to fail since it means things in the page aren't doing what you'd expect.  The Chrome inspect should show you the source of the JS with the error, if it's in your JS you'll need to fix it, if not it may be a bug in chromedriver.

Comment: Thank you, I just fix Javascript error, and the tests pass again.